# Problem with displaying Smarty template in Internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, smarty

I have converted my existing website to Smarty template (my very first project with 1 day of smarty experience under the belt)

Prior to conversion my website looked fine in IE and FF.

After the conversion FF still looks okay however in IE everything falls apart. 
I have tried comparing the source code in IE and FF and everything looks exactly the same.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We'd need to see the smarty code to provide any guidance.  I'm almost certain the issue with the smarty code you used.  We have a large site built with smarty templates - close to 1000 templates with another 300 or so of ones used with {include} - and the site look fine in IE7, 8, 9, and all other browsers (we explicitly don't support IE6).

Comment: What is the problem? Are you sure the issue is caused by Smarty? For 99% the problem is caused by not-IE-optimized HTML/CSS code that causes cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Prior to conversion my website looked fine in IE and FF.

Answer (score 1):

Since Smarty is just the templating system that generates the HTML sent to the browser, the issue probably occurred when you split up your existing site into parts. Unfortunately it isn't very easy to find out what is wrong with a full project on SO. That said, here are some tips on debugging the issue.

Load your old site and copy the source from the browser (doesn't matter which browser as the server sends the same HTML*).
Load your new site and copy the source from the browser.
Diff the two sources to find the differences.

I think that's the best place to start. If the new site is sending the exact same HTML to the browser, then it would seem that some resource isn't being loaded (bad link) or javascript isn't being executed in IE, which should be separate from Smarty. For that check IE's Developer Tools and make sure no CSS is getting a 404 and no js exceptions are being thrown.

**As long as you aren't modifying things on the server based off the User-Agent sent, which is not common.*